# JavaFX TreeItem css style for different class field

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I have TreeView filled by my own tree. In class Node I have field "type" which is one of NodeType. The problem is that I want have style for each type of NodeType, e.g. "type1" text color should be green, "type2" text color should be red. I'm new in javaFX. I found solution by james-d ( https://github.com/james-d/heterogeneous-tree-example ), but in this example css style depends on the class name, how can I make it for class field ?

[View of TreeView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTLLg.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is you want a `TreeCell` that styles differently depending on the `NodeType` of the `Node` contained within the `TreeItem` of said `TreeCell`. All via CSS. Am I correct?

Assuming I am correct, there are 2 ways I can think of to accomplish this; both of which work best if there is a small number of known `NodeType`s. The first involves the use of [PseudoClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html) and the second uses the same strategy as the JavaFX `Chart` API.

---

### First Option

Create a custom `TreeCell` that is tailored to using your `Node` type (i.e. specify the generic signature appropriately). In this custom `TreeCell` you declare as many `PseudoClass` static final fields as you need; one for each `NodeType`. Then you observe the `NodeType` of the whatever `Node` is currently displayed in the `TreeCell` and update the `PseudoClass` states accordingly.

Here is an example assuming `NodeType` is an `enum` that has two constants: `HAPPY` and `SAD`.

```
public class CustomTreeCell<T extends Node> extends TreeCell<T> {

    private static final PseudoClass HAPPY = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("happy");
    private static final PseudoClass SAD = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("sad");

    // this listener will activate/deactivate the appropriate PseudoClass states
    private final ChangeListener<NodeType> listener = (obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        pseudoClassStateChanged(HAPPY, newVal == NodeType.HAPPY);
        pseudoClassStateChanged(SAD, newVal == NodeType.SAD);
    };

    // use a weak listener to avoid a memory leak
    private final WeakChangeListener<NodeType> weakListener = /* wrap listener */;

    public CustomTreeCell() {
        getStyleClass().add("custom-tree-cell");
        itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            if (oldVal != null) {
                oldVal.nodeTypeProperty().removeListener(weakListener);
            }
            if (newVal != null) {
                newVal.nodeTypeProperty().addListener(weakListener);
                // need to "observe" the initial NodeType of the new Node item.
                // You could call the listener manually to avoid code duplication
                pseudoClassStateChanged(HAPPY, newVal.getNodeType() == NodeType.HAPPY);
                pseudoClassStateChanged(SAD, newVal.getNodeType() == NodeType.SAD);
            } else {
                // no item in this cell so deactivate all PseudoClass's
                pseudoClassStateChanged(HAPPY, false);
                pseudoClassStateChanged(SAD, false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then in your CSS file you can use:

```
.custom-tree-cell:happy {
    /* style when happy */
}

.custom-tree-cell:sad {
    /* style when sad */
}
```

---

### Second Option

Do what the JavaFX `Chart` API does when dealing with multiple series of data. What it does is dynamically update the `style class` of the nodes depending on the series' index in a list (e.g. `.line-chart-series-data-<index>` <-- probably not *exactly* this).

```
/*
 * Create a custom TreeCell like in the first option but
 * without any of the PseudoClass code. This listener should
 * be added/removed from the Node item just like weakListener
 * is above.
 */
ChangeListener<NodeType> listener = (obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    // You have to make sure you keep "cell", "indexed-cell", and "tree-cell"
    // in order to keep the basic modena styling.
    if (newVal == NodeType.HAPPY) {
        getStyleClass().setAll("cell", "indexed-cell", "tree-cell", "custom-tree-cell-happy");
    } else if (newVal == NodeType.HAPPY) {
        getStyleClass().setAll("cell", "indexed-cell", "tree-cell", "custom-tree-cell-sad");
    } else {
        getStyleClass().setAll("cell", "indexed-cell", "tree-cell"); // revert to regular TreeCell style
    }
};
```

Then in CSS:

```
.custom-tree-cell-happy {
    /* styles */
}

.custom-tree-cell-sad {
   /* styles */
}
```

---

Both of these options are really only viable when there is a small set of known types. It might become unmaintainable when you have something like 10+ `NodeType`s. It becomes pretty much impossible if the number of `NodeType`s is dynamic at runtime.

It might be easier to have `NodeType`, or some intermediate class/data structure, know what color the text should be and set the color programmatically based on the `NodeType`.

**Note: I quickly typed up the code in my answer and did not test it. There may be compiler errors, runtime exceptions, or logic errors in my code.**

---

**Edit**

Something else came to mind. My code above assumes that `NodeType` is held in a property and can be changed during runtime. If `NodeType` is static (unchanging) for each `Node` then the code can be vastly simplified. Instead of using any listeners you can simple override the following method declared in `javafx.scene.control.Cell`:

`protected void updateItem(Node item, boolean empty)`

This method is called every time a new item is set on the cell. Read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateItem-T-boolean-), however, as overriding this method requires certain things from the developer (such as calling the super implementation).

Comment: Really thanks for your answer ;) it was helpful for me. I didn't check first and second option, but the third one work for me (`NodeType` is static in my example). This is my working method:
https://pastebin.com/z3A4GuH1
I have question to you. Is it good solution to have about 8 calls to `pseudoClassStateChanged()` in my method? Also I would like to ask why when I use pseudoClasses arrow in `TreeView` dissapear ? (https://imgur.com/a/CFR7a). One more time thank you for a help @Slaw

Comment: @materaldo Having 8 calls to `pseudoClassStateChanged(...)` should be okay. Internally it tries to add/remove the `PseudoClass` to/from a set and only if successful - meaning there was an actual update - will it go forward with reapplying CSS. In other words, the implementation is very lazy/conservative and it should be fine even with a lot of calls.

Comment: @materaldo Regarding the missing arrow, I have no idea why that is happening. I just mocked something up real quick and the arrow stays for me. The issue could be with your CSS rules (you didn't provide a link showing the stylesheet).

Comment: my css rules are simple like `.tree-cell:type1 { -fx-backgroud: #color;}`, here you are https://pastebin.com/3EKGTTmR

Comment: I was making some code refactor and I checked `setDisclosureNode(null);` method. It is why my arrow disappeared :)

Comment: @materaldo the arrows disappear if styleClass is completely empty, e.g., if you forget to re-fill it with the default content cell", "indexed-cell", "tree-cell".